# Git Command to know current repository

Tags: git

Any command to know which remote repository currently I am connected to?

If I browse to a directory which contains a .git folder. Can I run any command to know which remote repository this .git folder is mapped to ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no 1:1 local:remote mapping for Git repos. Every repo can have several remotes, or even none at all.

You can use `git remote -v` to get a list of all remotes currently in your local repo's config. Note that these are only aliases for certain convenience, and you can directly fetch from and push to any remote repos by using their URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this with `git remote -v`. See `git help remote` for other `remote`-related options.

Answer (score 0):

```
git config -l | grep remote 
git remote 
git remote -v
```